# SQL - JOIN two tables and COUNT (also NULL values)

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've got these three tables (it's a table tennis game):

### table1: (goals, a user made, multiple rows)

id_goal
sp_id
game_id
time

### table2: (users, multiple rows)

id_user
username
info_text

### table3: (users_in_a_game, multiple rows)

id_uiag
game_id
sp_id

Now, I want to get all users from users_in_a_game, that played a game, want the name from users and the COUNT(goals) for every player, but the COUNT of the goals not in SUM, but for every single match in the specific row. So the result would be:

```
game1 - user1 - 50 goals
game1 - user2 - 20 goals

game2 - user3 - 12 goals
game2 - user1 - 7 goals

...
```

So far, I've coded this code:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(goals.sp_id) AS goals_per_game
FROM users_in_a_game
    LEFT JOIN goals ON users_in_a_game.game_id = goals.game_id
GROUP BY goals.sp_id;
```

The problem is, that if a player was participating in the game, but doesn't score a goal, he doesn't get listed AT ALL. So how can I fix that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That code is invalid in several ways and should raise an exception. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @jarlh I selected the sp_id, so I can use it for group by?

Comment: You should put all columns you SELECT in the GROUP BY, except goals.sp_id.

Comment: First, ditch the `*` in the select list. Then figure out what expressions (columns) we want in the GROUP BY clause, and repeat those same expressions (columns) in the SELECT list. If we have trouble figuring that out, then remove the aggregate expression, and return just the detail rows,  we can add an ORDER BY clause using the expressions we think we might want to group on. (HINT: we do not want goals.sp_id in the GROUP BY, that is totally wrong. Looks like what we want to group on is the game and the player (i.e. columns from the driving table)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to aggregate by the user id and game id.  I think:

```
SELECT ug.id_uiag, ug.game_id, COUNT(g.sp_id) AS goals_per_game
FROM users_in_a_game ug LEFT JOIN
     goals g
     ON ug.game_id = g.game_id
GROUP BY ug.id_uiag, ug.game_id;
```